# Using awk to print specific line with neighbour lines

Tags: awk, sed

Is it possible to print specific line with neighbour lines using awk or sed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk 'NR>=3&&NR<=5' input.txt
```

Print lines 3,4,5

Comment: For large files don't parse unnecessary lines  `awk 'NR>5{exit}NR>=3&&NR<=5'`

Comment: @sudo_O don't test the same condition multiple times to avoid redundant hard-coded values: `awk 'NR>=3; NR==5{exit}` or more efficiently `awk 'NR>=3{print; if (NR==5) exit}`.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '3,5p;5q' file
```

This will print lines 3 to 5 and quit following line 5.